# asp.net how to get back on previous page

Tags: asp.net

I have developed a role based application and i have roles like Administrator, Operator..on every page I am checking if current user have assigned role then its allowed ..in my case i want to restrict "Operators" when they type in url of "Administrator.aspx" and get inside..in that case if user was on PAGE A and tries to hit the administrator url it should redirect back to PAge A ..Page A can be any other page names also....how to achieve this I am trying this way but its not working..

```
       if (ViewState["URLReferrer"] == null)
            ViewState["URLReferrer"] = Request.UrlReferrer;

        if (!HttpContext.Current.User.IsInRole("Control User"))
        {
            //If user is trying to access the admin page ..send back to the page where he is coming from.
            Response.Redirect(Convert.ToString(ViewState["URLReferrer"]));
        }
```

Comment: getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error...

Answer (score 1):

I've tried it. UrlReferer has Uri type, but you need string to use Response.Redirect

```
if (Request.UrlReferrer == null || string.IsNullOrEmtpy(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri))
    Response.Redirect("defaultPage")
else
    Response.Redirect(Request.UrlReferrer.AbsoluteUri);
```

The above code works in my test web site. Try it.

Comment: Be wary that this is not 100% reliable. It's a host header that things like virus scanners and proxy servers can block. i'd use a querystring param instead.

Comment: getting "Object reference not set to an instance of an object." error.

Comment: do you mean that all links must have retrunUrl querystring?

Comment: to user239684, Maybe you are start debugging with the page that has this code, in this case there is no referer, so you need to check if it is not null, I will update my answer

Comment: I have no idea..i am new to asp.net...i guess behavior is different when type adminpage.aspx directly in url bar..what do u think or suggest how to setup all this.

Comment: I've updated code, if there is no urlreferer then it will redirect to your default page name

Comment: Danil it can be done with Request.UrlReferrer as i am already checking if user Role is not Admin then redirect back to Default page..so whats the use of UrlReferrer then? :) ..it would be lovely if redirects back to the page where user typed the "AdminPage.aspx" in url directly...hitting the url directly can we get the previous page url from history?

Comment: I did solve by creating a function ScriptManager.RegisterStartupScript(this, this.GetType(), "goback", "goback();", true); and in javascript i did .."history.go(-1);"

Comment: hmm, if you type directly in the address bar and want to track it, then I think the only one way is to use session object to hold history of your last page, and update it after checking that user can see the page content.

Comment: But in this case i need to update the session variables on every page?

Comment: Yep, however if you don't worry to have userInRole code checks on every page, why does it disturb you?